# text = sio.getvalue() ; Return 'text' not recognizing in the 'For' loop

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I am trying to read specific word from the PDF file , I used PDFMiner to convert the PDF to text (line by line) and used 'for' loop to find the word.

When I print the "text" I get the desired PDF content line by line.

But I used same "text" to read into 'For' loop to find the practicular word, my'For' loop not recognizing the "text".

Apart from below code I also tried to create a Test.txt('PDF_PlaceHolder.txt') file and reading, thats also not recognizing in 'For loop'

```
file = open("PDF_PlaceHolder.txt", "w")
file.write(PDFtext)
fname ='PDF_PlaceHolder.txt'
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
     line = line.rstrip()

from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter#process_pdf
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams

# from cStringIO import StringIO
# from io import BytestIO
from io import StringIO

Tax_Co = list()
Tax_Au = list()
line = list()

def pdf_to_text(pdfname):
     # PDFMiner boilerplate
     rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
     sio = StringIO()
     codec = 'utf-8'
     laparams = LAParams()
     device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, sio, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
     interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

# Extract text
     fp = open(pdfname, 'rb')
     for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        fp.close()

   # Get text from StringIO
     text = sio.getvalue()
     # Cleanup
     device.close()
     sio.close()
    return text

 # Local PDF File reading 
 pdfname ='Summary 5.pdf'
  # Passing to function
 PDFtext = pdf_to_text(pdfname)
 fh = PDFtext

  #Reading the line by line to find the content and next index word
  for line in fh:
     line = line.rstrip()
  # if line.startswith('From' ):
    if line.startswith('Tax Company Name:'):
        Tax_Company = line.split()
        print ("Tax Company Name:", Tax_Company[3])
     if line.startswith('Tax Authority:'):
        Tax_Aut = line.split()
        print ("Tax Authority:", Tax_Aut[2])
```

Expected result:

```
Tax Company : XY
Tax Authority : XZ
```

Now printing nothing.(blank)

Comment: Maybe the line has spaces in front of `Tax Company Name`, so it doesn't actually `startwith("Tax Company Name:")`? It would help if you showed the relevent part of the text where you say *When I print the "text" I get the desired PDF content line by line.*

Comment: Here the PDF content : W-X STATE AND LOCAL SUMMARY
Date:

03/08/2019

Tax Company Name:   XY      -    ABC Comapany.

Tax Authority: XZ -XZ Tax Authority
_____________________________________________________________________________________

Number of W-2 forms:
Federal wages, tips and other compensation:
Federal income Tax Withheld:
Social Security wages:
Social Security tips:
Social Security tax withheld:

Comment: Is there anyway to commit the "text" ? I used temporary file to store PDF content and used file.flush(), then the for loop is working.